# Image not viewable in folder

Tags: php, image, laravel, dir

I have an image encoded in a base64 string and i need it to save on a folder as a image.
This is the code:

```
$img = Input::get('myField');
        define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'C:/wamp/www/laravel/dentalRoyale/public/assets/profile/');
        $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
        $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
        $data = base64_decode($img);
        $file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';
        $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
```

Yeah, it saves on the profile folder. But i can't open the image which i badly need. How can i fix this? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "can't open?"  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed. The image is now viewable. I forgot to change this `str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img)` to this `str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $img),` because the type of my image is jpeg.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, are you absolutely certain that it's a png?

Secondly, `$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);` isn't needed. If anything, you'd need to do that in reverse if the string is uri encoded.

Try commenting out that line and checking that it's actually a PNG.